# Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy: No

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I am facing this problem over and over again and yet I did set `CORS: true`. I am using serverless and aws lambda. Here is the serverless snippet:

```
functions:

  authenticate:
    handler: auth.authenticate
    events:
      - http:
          path: /api/authenticate
          method: post
          cors: true
```

And here is the lambda:

```
module.exports.authenticate = (evt, ctx, done) => {

    let payload = JSON.parse(evt.body);
    
    connectToDatabase()
        .then(response => {
            let salt = response.users.setSalt();
            const account = {
                id: payload.id,
                username: payload.username,
                mobile: payload.mobile,
                salt: salt,
                password: response.users.setPassword(payload.password, salt),
                roles: payload.roles,
            }
            response.users.create(account)
                .then(user => {
                    done(null, {
                        statusCode: 200, 
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' 
                        },
                        body: response.users.generateJWT()
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    done (null, {
                        statusCode: 400,
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' 
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify(Boom.badRequest(JSON.stringify(err))),
                    });
                });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            done (null, {
                statusCode: 400,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' 
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(Boom.badRequest('Database connection failed')),
            });
        });
}
```

the error I am getting is:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'amazonapigateway/dev/api/authorize' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I am new to aws-lambda and serverless. Could use some help please.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you please add what your expected result is and what the actual result you are getting?

Comment: Please add the full error message displayed by the browser.  Also, if the XHR call was made with `xhr.withCredentials = true` then wildcard origins aren't allowed and "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" must also be set.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for reply mate. I am making a post request to `apigatewayurl` and getting `502` along with `Access to XMLHttpRequest at `someapigatewayurl` from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` this error message.

Comment: what does `response.users.generateJWT()` return?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a combination of two things:

1. If you get 502 from API Gateway, it means that lambda's response did not correspond to API Gateway requirements.
2. API Gateway never adds CORS headers to your response - it's your logic (lambda) responsibility. API Gateway can create an OPTIONS route, but not more.

Therefore, somewhere in your code you actually have an invalid response. I bet it's the line that says `response.users.generateJWT()`. Maybe it returns just a JWT string, but with your Content-Type header you explicitly said that you are returning JSON string. API Gateway could fail to validate your body and decided to return 502, obviously, neglecting any headers you added to your response object.

Comment: Hi, apologies for late response. I have found the root cause of this but still don't the fix for it. Here is the problem, my lambda is trying to connect with the database. its aurora serverless and takes time to connect. So when my lambda gets timeout and can't connect I am getting this error. Once aurora serverless cold start is over, and lambda gets the connection, it is working perfectly. I am new to lambda and serverless. Still can't fix it. Could use some help here.

Comment: well, can't really do nothing about that, except increasing lambda's timeout. You can, however, warm up your lambdas periodically, but such solution doesn't scale well

Comment: I have tried adding more time to my lambda. But since my lamba is with api gateway, timeout is 30s. In my experience, aurora server-less doesn't take 30s to warm up. But when calling from lambda, my lambda doesn't run for all of its 30s, checking the cloudwatch logs suggest, lambda timeout after 6.1s. I am bit confused here.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command in your terminal and then test it again.

curl -H "origin: originHost" -v "RequestedResource"

Eg:

If my originHost  = https://localhost:8081/
and my RequestedResource = https://example.com/

My command would be as below:

**curl -H "origin: https://localhost:8081/" -v "https://example.com/"**

If you can notice the following line then it should work for you.

**< access-control-allow-origin: ***

Hope this helps.